# Check if attribute property is set without try-catch;

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes, .net-core-2.0

The System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute has properties (such as AutoGenerateField, AutoGenerateFilter, Order). If any of these attrs not set, when I attempt to read, fall into error.

```
object valAttrProp ;
var atProp = attrInstance.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var propInfo in atProp)
{
   if (propInfo.CanRead )
   {
       try
       {
           // all bottom lines generate an exception... 
           // valAttrProp = propInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(attrInstance,null);  
           // valAttrProp = valAttrProp.GetAccessors()[0].Invoke(attrInstance, null);
           // even with direct accessor:
           // valAttrProp = ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrInstance).Order;

           valAttrProp = propInfo.GetValue(attrInstance);

       }
       catch 
       {
           valAttrProp = null;
       }

       if (valAttrProp != null)
       {    
          // ...proccessing
       }
   }
}
```

[attrInstance in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNLUJ.png)

How can I find out : Are attrs set or not without try-catch block?

Comment: Try using the `Get` methods, they seem to return `null` if the corresponding property has not been assigned to.

Comment: attempt to read the property call exeption.. see debugger screen.

Comment: but if property is set - the problem disappears.

Comment: ...Try using the Get methods...
I do not understand what is going on. Could you set an example.
 
Accessing the property occurs through the Reflection - and if the speech is about the accessor of the attribute object,
then I have no opportunity to call him directly.(Although even in this case an error occurs 
((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attrInstance).Order ).  

Attempting to read type accessors via the GetAccessors method, returning the same get_Order() method that invokes an error.   p.GetAccessors()[0].Invoke(attrInstance, null);

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood what Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen was talking about.

For many properties (for example, `AutoGenerateField`) there is a remark in the documentation:

> Do not use this property to access the AutoGenerateField property.
>   Instead, use the GetAutoGenerateField method.

But for some reason, there is no such remark for the `Order` field, however, it seems to me that in such a case it would be logical to place a link to the corresponding method
in the `GetGetMethod` field of the class `PropertyInfo`. But for some reason, there is a method `get_PropName` (probably a get-accessor?). I would like to receive via Reflection a link to the desired method,

Otherwise, the solution is bad:

```
object val = null;

// bad line
var getMethogInfo = attrInstance.GetType().GetMethod("Get" + propInfo.Name);

if (getMethogInfo != null)
{
    val = getMethogInfo.Invoke(attrInstance, null);
}
else
{
    try
    {
       val = attrInstance.GetValue(at);
    }
    catch
    {
       val = null;
    }
}
```